# Vuejs Render list of Array based on key values

Tags: vue.js

I have a dataArray with data like this:

`dataArray: {'stat1': 'stat1stat', 'stat2': 'stat2stat', 'stat3': 'stat3stat'}`

and so on with hundreds of statistics in the array.

I have been outputting things hard coded in the vue template like this:

`{{dataArray.stat2}}`
`{{dataArray.stat3}}`
..etc

What I would like to do is have a new array that specifies the keys I want to render. So something like this:

`dataToShow: ['stat2', 'stat3']`

And then somehow I could do a loop or v-for to only show the data that is in `dataToShow`

I've tried a few different ways and I can't get it to work. I think it needs to be a computed property but it isn't working.

Can anyone give some advice on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be this?

```html
<template v-for="property in dataToShow">
  {{ dataArray[property] }}
</template>
```

Plus any relevant markup for each entry.

`dataToShow` could be a computed property as you've suggested but it could just as easily be in your `data`:

```js
data () {
  return {
    dataArray: {
      stat1: 'stat1stat',
      // etc.
    },

    dataToShow: ['stat2', 'stat3']
  }
}
```

Comment: wow that is so simple. it works perfectly. i was trying to make it too complicated